# How to extract data from two column as i am missing a regexp_match(..) like function

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

On a MS SQL Server version " Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM) - 14.0.1000.169 (X64)"

I am Read Only.

I Have a table T with items and two columns : a:nvarchar(255) and b:nvarchar(255)

I need to have a new column with the serial number of the items:

- sometimes it is in a, if not the SN is replaced by a number like 1.2.3
- sometimes it is in b, in a description field like this "..text.. SN: A1234Z567890, ..text.."

How can I build a SELECT query to extract the SN working in each case?
As I have no access right to create functions.

In PostgreSQL, I would have uses regexp_match(...), but I cannot find the same in SQL Server.

On PostgresSQL server I would have written a request like this one:

SELECT Coalesce( regexp_match(a, '([1-9A-Z]*?)'), regexp_match(b, '.*?SN\ :([1-9A-Z]*?)')
FROM T

How can I make it work on MS SQL Server?

Sample Data:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (a nvarchar(255), b nvarchar(255))
insert into @t values
  ('1.2.344', 'blah blah SN: A123Z4567, blah blah')
, ('B2234567', 'irrelevant stuff not a serial 123')
,  ('1.2.345', 'blah blah (SN: C32ZZ4567, blah) blah')
,  ('1.2.345', 'blah blah (No Serial at all here blah) blah')
, ('', '');
```

Expected output as an extra column:

```
serialnumber
==========
A123Z4567
B2234567
C32ZZ4567
NULL
NULL
```

I tried to use the same request as on a PostreSQL:

```
SELECT Coalesce( regexp_match(A, '([1-9]*?)'), regexp_match(B, '.*?SN\ :([1-9]*?)') as serialnumber
FROM T
```

But as I do not find a simple way to have a regexp_match function, I am lost as I do not manage to proceed.

===
Second try with Allmhuran code solution:

```
SELECT
  a
, b
, patindex('%SN: %', b) as pi
, serialnumber = case
    when a > '' and a not like '%[^0-9A-Z]%' then a
    when b > '' then CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255), patindex('%SN: %', b))
--  when b > '' then substring(
--                     b, 
--                     4 + patindex('%SN: %', b), 
--                     charindex(
--                        ',', 
--                        b, 
--                        4 +  patindex('%SN: %', b)
--                     ) - 4 - patindex('%SN: %', b)
--              )
    else null
   end
FROM T
```

But the part:

```
patindex('%SN: %', b)
```

return 0 instead of the expected index

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results *as text tables* in the question.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to provide an expression that is guaranteed to be correct 100% of the time, but...

As a query:

```
-- create some sample data
create table t(a nvarchar(255), b nvarchar(255));
insert t values (null, 'blah blah SN: 12345, blah blah'), ('123', 'irrelevant stuff'), ('', '');


-- alter the table to add the expression as a computed column:
alter table t add serialNumber as 
case
   when a > '' and a not like '%[^0-9A-Z]%' then a
   when patindex('%SN: %, %', b) > 0 then 
      substring(
         b, 
         4 + patindex('%SN: %, %', b), 
         charindex(
            ',', 
            b, 
            4 + patindex('%SN: %, %', b)
         ) - 4 - patindex('%SN: %, %', b)
      )
   else null
end;
```

Comment: Great, I modified it a bit as I have no create right, and my serials contains some letters also. Otherwise it seems to work fine.

Comment: Could you also add the version without the cross apply please ?

Comment: I have added the distributed version, as well as the statement you could execute to add the expression as a computed column

Comment: I keep getting some error message : "Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function." do you have an idea why ?

Comment: You mentioned you had to modify it a bit to account for a wider variety of patterns. It is likely that the modification has caused the query to match a pattern that appears "too early" - note that my expressions use the value 5 in various places. That's because the serial number you are looking for in `B` appears 5 characters after the start of the `SN: ` pattern - but that's only true given the specific examples provided. If you modify your question and include the changes you made to my query, we can look for the issue.

Comment: OK, I see your edit. The problem is that your modified pattern `'%SN: [0-9A-Z],%'` means "find a substring starting with `SN:`, which then has a space, and then *exactly one character* which is either a digit or a letter from A to Z, and then a comma". The "exactly one character" is the problem. What you'll have to do instead is just use the pattern `%SN: %, %` to find the start of the serial number bit in `b`.

Comment: I just added what I tried based on your solution and sample data in my question. I had to modify the regex patindex('%SN: [0-9A-Z],%', b) as I have letters in SN, but I am unsure if it is good or not, as I am used to usual regex but not MS regex...

Comment: ok good! thank for the help. I i also had to handle special case when there is no SN at all and patindex returns 0.

Comment: Ooops, you're right, I will modify that part of my answer, but I'll leave the pattern as-is, since your modifications depend upon the specific format you are looking for